# Not a Valid Valid Housing

Tags: terraria

Ok so i made a house in terraria and it was fine untill a while later when i made more houses on top of it. It just stops working at like my 5th house (about 36 blocks high it stopped working) and my npc's wont move there because they say its not valid! please help

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your housing, please?

Comment: 1. Check background walls. 2. Check table/chair. 3. Check light source. 4. Check for nearby corruption. I would add "check size", but I imagine you're making all of these rooms the same size, so it's probably not that. Otherwise, a screen shot would be needed.